# Deadlock while updating rows and inserting new ones

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I'm working with SQL Server 2012 Express Edition and I getting this error:

```
Transaction (Process ID 53) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has
been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

I've added these two commands to show more information about it:

```
DBCC TRACEON(1204, -1)
DBCC TRACEON(1222, -1)
```

With these two commands I get this [log](http://pastebin.com/K3mPmgH4). But I don't know how to find where the problem is.

Executing `sp_lock` I have identified that the problem is on table `TRZIC.dbo.CODES` and it has a `PAG` type.

On this table I'm updating rows and inserting new ones at the same time.

Any advice? How can I solve this deadlock?

Comment: Can you show your code? Usually it's a simple fix.

Answer (score 3):

I bet your code does something like this logic:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.table WHERE key = @key)
BEGIN
  UPDATE dbo.table SET foo = @bar WHERE key = @key;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  INSERT dbo.table(key, foo) VALUES(@key, @bar);
END
```

If so, just do this:

```
UPDATE dbo.table SET foo = @bar WHERE key = @key;
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
  INSERT dbo.table(key, foo) VALUES(@key, @bar);
END
```

That meaningless first `SELECT` is just a wasted seek (or scan if you are not identifying row(s) by something that can seek), and can often be the cause of deadlocks when you have many users simultaneously running this same piece of code.